# Can we store SQL query in XSL variable

Tags: sql, xml, variables, xslt, xpath

Can we store a SQL query in a xsl variable?

```
<xsl:variable name="Query" select="'SELECT X FROM ABC WHERE ID>=2'"/>
```

If I write like that I am getting error for illegal '>' found,and I have tried another way like this

```
 <xsl:variable name="Query" select="'SELECT X FROM ABC WHERE ID gt;=2'"/>
```

Then I am getting illegal '>' element error...

Please help me how to store a query in a variable.

I am using a big query which involves joins and all SQL stuff..I facing the same issue please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:variable name="Query">SELECT X FROM ABC WHERE ID >= 2</xsl:variable>
```

or probably more safe and flexible way using `<![CDATA[]]>`:

```
<xsl:variable name="Query"><![CDATA[SELECT X FROM ABC WHERE ID >= 2]]></xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the ampersand character. Use this...

```
<xsl:variable name="Query" select="'SELECT X FROM ABC WHERE ID &gt;=2'"/>
```

(`&` inserted just before gt;)

---

Please be aware that there is a subtle difference in outcome between

```
(a)  <xsl:variable name="var-a" select="'some text'"/>
```

and...

```
(b)  <xsl:variable name="var-b">some text</xsl:variable>
```

Option (a) results in $var-a being a node-set (XSLT 1.0) or sequence (XSLT 2.0) containing one node - that node being a text node.

Option (b) results in $var-b being a node-set/sequence containing one node - that node being a result-tree-fragment (XSLT 1.0) or a document node (XSLT 2.0), which in turn contains the text node.